# Why won't my USB drive power down on eject?

Tags: hard-drive, time-machine, sleep-wake, spotlight, mojave

I've just upgraded from High Sierra to Mojave. I have a Lacie Porsche USB-C drive that I use for Time Machine backups. In High Sierra when I ejected the drive, it would power off and I could safely unplug it. However, now it doesn't spin down and I can't safely unplug. All I can do is put my Mac to sleep which in turn powers down the drive.

I have tried excluding the drive from Spotlight indexing and even disabling indexing altogether but this hasn't helped.

Anyone else having this problem or have a solution?

Comment: try this in Terminal to find out who is using it `lsof | grep DODO`

Comment: so nobody is using it !

Comment: If the drive is unmounted you can safely unplug it, regardless of the power status. USB is completely hotplug compatible.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Although it seems like the drive is unmounted, it stills sounds like it is active and makes a nasty screeching sound if I just unplug it. This didn't happen before I upgraded to Mojave.

Comment: Just a quick update on this. The problem seems to have resolved itself...

Comment: Did it resolve permanently? The same issue keeps coming back again and again for me.

Comment: @Szabolcs I can't say it is permanently fixed as I have had it happen recently again, possibly following a macOS update. However, this weekend it has been ok following a restart...

Answer (score -1):

Use this Terminal command  `sudo lsof | grep DODO`

to find out who is using the USB.

Wait for it to respond, it might take 10 seconds.

If no one is using it, it is safe to eject the disk (pull out).

I did not answer your question "Why it does not Power Down" ? I do not know, probably missing the handshake saying I am done.

Comment: Doesn't that need a sudo?

Comment: @Mark not on my Mac, and since it is only read command why would it need sudo ?

Comment: Because lsof on its own won't show files open by root and other users https://ss64.com/osx/lsof.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am not sure what the problem was but it has resolved itself...

Comment: What is "DODO"?