# Why has my hard drive started spinning-up each time I eject it?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, disk-utility, filesystem

When I eject the hard drive, the disk starts to slow down but then the disk starts spinning at full speed about a second later. The hard drive is not mounted but it is still spinning. I’m afraid to unplug it when it’s in this state. If I wait about 10 minutes, it eventually stops spinning. I’d rather not have to wait around that long.

This only started happening about a month ago. It might have been due to a software update but I’m not sure. Why is this happening and how do I fix it?

Comment: If the disk has been ejected successfully, I don't think you should be afraid to unplug it.

Comment: @nekomatic I can still hear the read-write head moving.

Comment: Technically a duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/338166/45492

Comment: It is safe to disconnect. If you hear the read-write head the disk is doing some internal data management which should be fail-safe.

Comment: @n1000 I guess I'll take your word for it. This wasn't happening before updating to Mojave. I'd prefer the disk power down when I eject it.

Comment: @n1000 If you’re quick, you can still claim the free 50 rep.

Comment: You too @nekomatic

Comment: Thanks! I wouldn't be comfortable to give an authorative answer here. I am not sure why your disk spins up again and I did not find a good reference for my claims... BTW, I have some no-name disk enclosures that will also spin up after eject, as opposed to my brand USB-drives.

Comment: @n1000 It will probably fix itself after a software update. I think that’s what caused the issue in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I updated to macOS 10.14.4 and the issue has mysteriously resolved itself. A software update caused the problem and a software update fixed it.